# PHP Prepared Statements handle duplicate entry

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, error-handling, prepared-statement

I have a problem, I am not able to handle a duplicate entry with prepared statements.

I want to end the program when a duplicate entry appears. This is what I have been trying to do:

```
function insert_vulnerability ($CVE, $Description, $Date, $Score, $Type){


    $conn = connection();

    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO Vulnerabilities (CVE, Description, Date, Score, Type)
                           VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");




    $stmt->bind_param("sssis", $CVE, $Description, $Date, $Score, $Type);

    if ( false === $stmt ) {

       die('prepare() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($mysqli->error));

    }


    $stmt->execute();

    $conn->close();


}
```

When not using prepared statements I handled the error this way and everything worked perfectly:

```
function insert_vulnerability ($CVE, $Description, $Date, $Score, $Type){


    $conn = connection();

    $Description = htmlspecialchars($Description);



    $sql = "INSERT INTO Vulnerabilities (CVE, Description, Date, Score, Type)
    VALUES ('".$CVE."', '".$Description."', '".$Date."', '".$Score."', '".$Type."')";

    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        //echo "New record created successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
        $conn->close();
        die();

    }

    $conn->close();

}
```

So how do I get the same result with prepared statements ¿?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: So what is your problem? You title your question about duplicates, now you ask about error handling.

Comment: @u_mulder you're right, my bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just connect the checking inside the `$stmt->execute()` to see if the prepared statement did work properly.

```
function insert_vulnerability ($CVE, $Description, $Date, $Score, $Type){
    $conn = connection();

    $stmt = $conn->prepare('
        INSERT INTO Vulnerabilities (CVE, Description, Date, Score, Type)
        VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
    ');

    $stmt->bind_param('sssis', $CVE, $Description, $Date, $Score, $Type);
    if($stmt->execute()) { // true, success, else error
        echo 'New record created successfully';
    } else {
        echo $conn->error;
    }

    $conn->close();
}
```

Just to note, you have an undefined variable on your prepared statement side:

```
$mysqli->error
```